# Multiple Propositions in a Statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is a statement like "The person who lives in Los Angeles traveled to New York." a single proposition *A* or two propositions *A ^ B* where *A* is "The person lives in Los Angeles." and *B* is "The person traveled to New York."?

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to do...

Comment: What if I am just trying to represent that statement "The person who lives in Los Angeles traveled to New York." alone. What is the best way to treat it?

Comment: No "best way"; $P$ can be enough.

Comment: I think it is correct to use one proposition. In most of cases it is convenient to separate into two or more propositions when there is more than one subject or predicate in the same sentence. Can you do that here? If the statement said "The person, who lives in Los Angeles, traveled to New York and buys some stuff to her mother" it would be correct to use two propositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically speaking "The person who lives in Los Angeles traveled to New York." is just one statement.

If we break it in two parts such as "The person who lives in Los Angeles" and "traveled to New York." we can not assign a truth value to the individual parts.

On the other hand if you have "Mr. X lives in Los Angeles and traveled to New York." then we have two statements.

"Mr. X lives in Los Angeles" and " Mr. X traveled to New York" since we can assign truth value to each part.